# react testing library typescript render thinks I provide type not value

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning testing in typescript, and I followed tutorial for JS, everything I do seems to work on the video, but when I pass component to render function it thinks it is a type not a component, I tried to assign it to a variable and then passing it, but the result is this same, can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { OtherTesting, Props } from "./OtherTesting";

describe("<OtherTesting />", () => {
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it("renders increment button", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<OtherTesting />); // OtherTesting' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof OtherTesting'?ts(2749)
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your test file a `.ts` or `.tsx` file? Assuming everything else is set up correctly, if you're testing react components in typescript, your test file should be `.tsx` and not `.ts`.

Comment: that worked! thank you @I'mJoeToo